# Are the irreducible components appearing in the resolution of singularities of a Hilbert modular surface defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, shimura-varieties, compactifications

It seems to me that this is claimed in van der Geer's "Hilbert modular surfaces" on p. 245 at the beginning of XI.2 (without justification).

My current state of belief/knowledge:

- The connected components of the Shimura variety are defined over the reflex field $\mathbb{Q}$ (when as I assume there is no level structure) by Deligne.
- The resolution of the cusps is described in the preceding chapter X in a way that can be carried out gluing boundary components over $\mathbb{Q}$. This should hold more generally for toroidal compactifications of Shimura varieties, replacing $\mathbb{Q}$ by a connected component's field of definition.
- This leaves the resolution of the elliptic points. Why should these even be rational points and their resolution components be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$?